# Alternatives to using "having" clause for alias fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this somewhat complex sql query that works ok without the final where clause. I'm looking to filter some records using the column `unreviewed_records` which is an alias

Problem is that I get an error saying `unreviewed_records` cannot be found. I found some information saying that alias fields are not permitted to be used in where clauses and I'm not sure what's the best way to fix this. Considered using a computed column but I'm not sure how that works yet and I'm hoping there's an easier fix to the query.
Also I find that switching to using the "`having`" clause work for aliases, but I'll only resort to this if there's no better alternative, to avoid the performance hit.

Any pointers would be helpful :)

```
select 
        r_alias.serv_id, r_alias.node_id,
            SUM(g_alias.total_records)- SUM(r_alias.reviewed_records) AS unreviewed_records,

            SUM(r_alias.reviewed_records) AS reviewed_records,
            SUM(g_alias.total_records) AS total_records,
        FROM (
        SELECT prs.serv_id,
               prs.node_id,
               SUM(prs.reviewed_records) AS reviewed_records,
        FROM p_rev_server prs
        WHERE
             prs.area_id = 3
            AND prs.subId = 3
            AND prs.sId = 12
            
        GROUP BY prs.serv_id, prs.node_id, prs.domain_name
    ) r_alias
        INNER JOIN (SELECT
               serv_id,
               node_id,
              SUM(pgs.total_records) AS total_records,
            FROM p_gen_serve pgs
            WHERE pgs.area_id = 3
            AND pgs.subId = 3
            AND pgs.sId = 12
            AND pgs.total_records > 0
            
            GROUP BY pgs.serv_id, pgs.node_id, pgs.domain_name
    ) g_alias
          ON g_alias.serv_id = r_alias.serv_id AND g_alias.node_id = r_alias.node_id

        LEFT JOIN p_cust_columns cust_cols
          ON cust_cols.node_id = r_alias.node_id AND cust_cols.serv_id = r_alias.serv_id

          where (((NOT (unreviewed_records IS NULL)) AND (unreviewed_records = 5)))

          group by r_alias.serv_id, r_alias.node_id
          order by g_alias.node_id ASC
          limit 25
```

Comment: there is no other way, if you want to use the aliases as having will filter after the query was performned, else write the hole code again in the where cluase

Comment: @nbk please elaborate.

Comment: Anything in the `SELECT` clause cannot be accessed in the `WHERE` clause because `SELECT` can (and in this case does) contain aggregate data which cannot be evaluated until after the data is filtered with the `WHERE` clause. `HAVING` works because the aggregate functions have been evaluated by then and the data is there. The only alternative to `HAVING` that I can see is just simply splitting this into multiple queries.

Comment: run this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=48e24189fa7516e3f298f7016a9d1dd7 @SamAko

Comment: No offense but unless a part of some custom report or a DB migration script,  I hate to see such convoluted queries.  Using multiple inner queries without worrying a bit about what will it do the performance or maintainability of the code.  If its a part of application code, please 1) use a stored procedure instead - there you can use the temp tables, which would make the whole thing so much easier to maintain + stored procedures are fast! 2) Try to simplify the query by using advances sql constructs (e.g. views, or break down the queries etc) 3) create views if necessary.

Comment: *to avoid the performance hit* - what performance hit? Using `having` to filter aggregated results is correct; your query as shown doesn't look particularly performant however; if you are using latest versions of MySql you could simplify and improve using lateral joins.

Comment: @Tintin moving parts of a query to a view or stored procedure just obfuscates what it is doing, making it harder to maintiain; it certainly isn't going to make a poorly performing query suddenly well performing.  That said, sometimes using multiple common table expressions can help make a query more readable and easier to test the performance of just part

Comment: @nbk query is failing, aggregate functions are not allowed in where clauses

Comment: @ysth - _"moving parts of a query to a view or stored procedure ...making it harder to maintain; it"_  - Respectfully disagree on many levels.  A well written stored procedure is much much easier to maintain and understand rather than a convoluted query.  Regarding performance, an _indexed_ view would greatly enhance the performance. Stored procedures in modern SQL servers wouldn't in themselves increase  performance, but in my instances it provides you ways to reconstruct queries to make the end execution much faster (e.g. create a temp table and reuse it in joins instead of inner queries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason aliases are not allowed in a WHERE clause is that the expressions in the SELECT list are not evaluated until after the rows are filtered by the WHERE clause. So it's a chicken-and-egg problem.

The easiest and most common alternative is a derived table:

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM (
    SELECT a, b, a+b AS c
    FROM mytable
    WHERE b = 1234
) AS t
WHERE c = 42;
```

This example shows that you can put some filtering conditions inside the derived table subquery, so you can at least reduce the result set partially, before the result of the subquery is turned into a temporary table.

Then in the outer query, you can reference a column that was derived from an expression in the select-list of the subquery. In this example, it's the `c` column.

The CTE approach is basically the same, it creates a temporary table to store the result of the inner query (the CTE), and then you can apply conditions to that in the outer query.

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT a, b, a+b AS c
    FROM mytable
    WHERE b = 1234
)
SELECT a, b, c
FROM t
WHERE c = 42;
```

The CTE solution is not better than the derived-table approach, unless you need to reference the CTE multiple times in the outer query, i.e. doing a self-join.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you are kind of SOL, WHERE can't know what an alias will be. So, frankly, a CTE, common table expression, is probably your best bet here. It should work, though not all RDBMS really support them (MySQL for example only in version 8).